# I have a list of dictionaries from a csv file, how can I copy that dictionaries to there own dictionary using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, dictionary

Hi Im very new to python, so all I need is for somone to point me in the right direction.
Okay I have a csv file with the top row as the keys and the first column as the dictionary (name). See csv example file. This part I understand, but what my code does so far is it pass the whole thing inside a variable say called reader2. This is what I did so far:

The test2.csv:

```
type,key1,key2,key3

summary,4,2.5,8.4

summary,3,9.4,3.6

summary,2,2.5,7.4

detail,4,5.3,3.6

detail,3,9,6.7

random,3,7.6,4.4

random,6,34.4,76.4

summary,7,6.7,53.3

summary,7,6.7,53.3
```

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import csv

reader2 = csv.DictReader(open('test2.csv'))

for summary in reader2:
 print summary
```

How can i get this to extract one dictionary after another and maybe assign it to a new dict with the same name? Or how do you iterate through this dict and use only the the key values according there dictionary names...remember the csv file. The value inside this file gets determined by the top header keys, and the type is the first column. I will then later work out how to play around with those values that correspond with the types.

As I said, I don't want you to do the whole thing, I just need some guidelines.

Comment: Can you provide the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to be doing much processing with these data, you will probably benefit from [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org). This supplies the DataFrame object which more naturally matches the kind of data you have here, and allows you to do things like this:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv('test2.csv')

print df.groupby('type').sum()
```

Which yields

```
         key1  key2  key3
type                     
detail      9  17.7  73.7
random     39  55.5  94.3
summary    24  33.9  80.6
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick respond... Just want to confirm. do i need to download the pandas module?

Comment: If you're familiar with python package installation, you can have a look at [these instructions](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html), but I'm picking up you're a novice at python, so it might be better to use a distribution that includes a number of packages, like [winpython](http://code.google.com/p/winpython/), which includes pandas and a number of other useful packages.

Comment: Thanks, but its already installed. I have found some powerful data analysis that one can do with this pandas. My problem not solved yet, but i'm quicker on my way to success now :)